Definition of expectation value for momentum
I think this is probably a stupid question but I'm confused over how the expectation value for momentum is calculated. It is always given as $$⟨⟩ = ⟨|\hat{p}⟩ = −\hbar∫^*()\frac{d()}{dx}x$$ But from what I understand, the definition of the expectation value is $$⟨f(X)⟩ = ∫f(x)P(x)dx,$$ so in this case would $P(x)$ not be the $()^*()$, as the wave function multiplied by its conjugate gives the probability distribution, resulting in the expression $$−\hbar∫(()^*())\frac{d()}{dx}x?$$ Clearly I'm missing some basic understanding here so would really appreciate any help!

Please fix the equations. There are several typos.

"It is always given as..." No, it is not always given in that form. You can calculate it in any basis you want.

Does this answer your question? Two ways of calculating the expectation value of momentum

You can also see this explained in Messiah's Quantum Mechanics, Volume 1, Chapter IV, Section 5, titled "Mean Values of Functions of r of of p"

(And section 2)

In the $x$-representation, the expectation value of the momentum operator $P$ in a (pure) state $|\psi\rangle$ described by the (position space) wave function $\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle$ is obtained by computing $$\langle \psi |P |\psi\rangle=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \! dx \, \psi(x)^\ast (-i \hbar \psi^\prime(x)).$$ Alternatively, you could compute $\langle \psi |P|\psi\rangle$ using the momentum space wave function $$\tilde{\psi}(p)=\langle p| \psi\rangle=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \! dx \, \langle p |x\rangle \langle x |\psi\rangle =\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \! dx \, \frac{e^{-ipx/\hbar}}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}} \, \psi(x)$$ in the expression $$\langle \psi |P |\psi\rangle = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \! dp \, p \, |\tilde{\psi}(p)|^2, $$ where  $|\tilde{\psi}(p)|^2$ is the probability distribution in momentum space.
More generally, the expectation value of some function $f(P)$ of the momentum operator in the state $|\psi\rangle$ is given by $$\langle\psi |f(P) |\psi \rangle= \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \! dp \, f(p) \, |\tilde{\psi}(p)|^2.$$

For any function $F(\vec r)$ of position $\vec r$, the expectation value is defined as:
$$
\langle F\rangle = \int d^3r F(\vec r) P(\vec r)\;,\tag{1}
$$
where $P(\vec r)$ is the probability density in real space.
For any function $G(\vec p)$ of position $\vec p$, the expectation value is defined as:
$$
\langle G\rangle = \int d^3r G(\vec p) \Pi(\vec r)\;,\tag{2}
$$
where $\Pi(\vec p)$ is the probability density in momentum space.

In quantum mechanics, when a system is described by a wave function $\Psi(\vec r)$, which are the components of $|\Psi\rangle$ in real space, the expectation value of Eq. (1) is evaluated as:
$$
\langle F\rangle = \int d^3r F(\vec r) |\Psi(\vec r)|^2\;,
$$
i.e., using $P(\vec r) = |\Psi(\vec r)|^2$.
Let the Fourier transform of $\Psi(\vec r)$ be defined as
$$
\tilde\Psi(\vec p) = \int \frac{d^3r}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\Psi(\vec r) e^{-i\vec p\cdot \vec r}\;,
$$
where the factor of $(2\pi)^{3/2}$ is just one of many conventions (some people put the entire $(2\pi)^3$ factor on one side of the transform), and where I have chosen units such that $\hbar=1$. The $\tilde \Psi(\vec p)$ are the components of $|\Psi\rangle$ in the momentum basis.
The expectation value of Eq. (2) is evaluated as:
$$
\langle G\rangle = \int d^3r G(\vec p) |\tilde \Psi(\vec p)|^2\;,
$$
i.e., using $\Pi(\vec p)=|\tilde \Psi(\vec p)|^2$.

As shown in many introductory quantum mechanics books (e.g., Messiah's), we can also write Eq. (1) as:
$$
\langle F\rangle = \int d^3r \tilde \Psi(\vec p)^* F(i\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec p}) \tilde \Psi(\vec p)\;.
$$
And we can also write Eq. (2) as:
$$
\langle G\rangle = \int d^3r \Psi(\vec r)^* G(-i\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec r}) \Psi(\vec r)\;.
$$
